# How to change API RGB color data to actual color sample in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, json

I write the code like below and

```
<p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.mode.rgb_color}</p>
```

I got the color data like the following photo.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du16U.png)

However, I want to show like the picture below

(how I call this? color something? it's not color picker)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhXyp.png)

The picture is the screen of the mobile app, and I would like the web app to have the same design as the mobile app as much as possible.

Is such an expression possible in React.js?

If it is possible, how?

Json

```
"mode": {
    "rgb_color": [
        255,
        255,
        255
    ],
}
```

React.js

```
          {schedules.map(schedule => (
            <div className="each_scheduled" key={schedule.id}>
              <div>
                <p className="scheduled_p">Color</p>
                <p className="scheduled_p">{schedule.mode.rgb_color}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
```

Comment: What style library you are using for your app? For example styled-components or chakraUI, or tailwindCSS. Nothing used any of them?

Comment: just pure CSS and bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that:

```
<div>
   <p className="scheduled_p">Color</p>
   <div className="color_container" style={{ backgroundColor: convertToColor(schedule.mode.rgb_color) }} />
</div>
```

your css file:

```
color_container {
 width: 24px;
 height: 24px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

convertToColor function:

```
const convertToColor = ([r, g, b]) => {
 return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
};
```